# In which version of WordPress was the new gallery shortcode implemented?

Tags: gallery, wordpress-version

As of WordPress 3.5, as I'm sure you all know, the gallery shortcode generated from the media uploader changed and now includes a list of image IDs.

The gallery shortcode codex page says the following:

> "It's important to note that this style of gallery shortcode is not
>   new to 3.5, however it is much easier to generate and manage with the
>   new Media Workflow introduced in 3.5."

Does anyone know what the minimum WP version is, in which this style of gallery shortcode will still work?

Comment: Do you mean when the `ids` attribute was introduced?

Comment: @birgire Yes exactly, sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `/wp-includes/media.php`, where the Gallery Shortcode is defined, first appears in [WordPress 2.5](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/2.5/wp-includes/media.php).

It has the **`id`** (singular) attribute to refer to the `post_parent`:

```
$attachments = get_children("post_parent=$id ...
```

---

The **`ids`** (plural) attribute appears in [WordPress 3.5](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-includes/media.php), and is used to `include` attachments:

```
if ( ! empty( $attr['ids'] ) ) {
    $attr['include'] = $attr['ids'];
}
...
$_attachments = get_posts( array('include' => $include
```

---

PS: I've updated the Codex, now [it reads](http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode) (updates in bold):

> ***Since WordPress 2.5** and up until 3.5, the gallery shortcode [...]*
>   [...]
>   *It's important to note that this style of gallery shortcode is not new to 3.5, **previously we could use the `include` attribute**.*

Comment: Thanks for this, but just to clarify are you saying that the gallery shortcode has always accepted this ID format?

Comment: Answer updated, hope it's clearer now.

Comment: It sounds like I might've just misunderstood the part of the codex page quoted in my original question. It sounds like it's saying that the IDs-style shortcode wasn't brand new in 3.5, but maybe it just means the gallery shortcode in general.

Comment: Oh, yes, I see the confusion. Updated Answer and Codex again.

Comment: Aha! That makes much more sense now, thanks muchly.